# Relation "typeorm_metadata" already exists

Tags: node.js, migration, typeorm, node.js-typeorm

I have been having difficulty running migrations on the server, migrations work perfectly on my local machine but every time I push to the server, the migrations don't work. So today, I decided to connect my PC to the Server Database with the server credentials.

When I tried to run the migrations manually, The image below was the result I got:

[image]

How do I go about solving this problem?

Comment: I had the same issue while upgrading from typeorm 0.2.34 to 0.2.45.
One of the devs in my team had added a migration to create the missing table typeorm_metadata following the advice on [this comment](https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm/issues/4923#issuecomment-664428271).  

However, the issue was fixed in one of the versions in between. Can you check that you don't have a migration that manually creates this table?